# c# controlling word file table

Tags: c#, ms-word, visual-studio-2017

I need to create a new word 2016 file, using VS2017, insert content (that's the easy part), and also to control it like doing the following:

- Merge certain cells in same row, or same column
- Define Right to Left or LTR
- color the text/the background.
  and more similar tasks.

I can open a document using

```
using Microsoft.Office;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
```

I can add text and save the document, yet still I don't see a way to fine control the color/direction and more parameters. After reading the documentation, it seems that this is probably not supported, unless I missed it.
I would appreciate if anyone can guide to a detailed documentation how to edit a word file from C# program.
Anyway, I can bypass it by creating an excel file which is simple using Interop and then insert it.

Comment: have you heard about open xml sdk ?

Comment: As stated, this question is too broad. Please review the site guidelines for asking questions in the [help]. Besides not targeting one, specific issue, the question also does not provide a starting point (the code you already have). To help yourself: record what you want to do in a VBA macro in order to get the basic syntax, which can then be carried over to C#.

Comment: I use docx to open the document. Is that XML? The code I use is: "var doc = DocX.Create(word_fname);". I can create the table and insert rows with data, but I couldn't format/merge the cells using C#.

Comment: @Cindy Meister: I tried recording such a macro with VBA, and got:"Selection.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphRight".  I tried with my code (Table table = doc.AddTable(tableSize, 3);) and I didnt find a correct way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working solution for merging cells in a table, using VS2017 c#

var doc = DocX.Create(word_fname);
 Table table = doc.AddTable(tableSize, 3);
table.Rows[row_cnt].MergeCells(1, 2); // to merge the 2nd & 3rd cells in the specific row